# Как изменить цвет метки gtk?

Tags: c, gtk

Сделал это:

```
PangoColor color;
pango_color_parse(&color,"#cccc00000000");
PangoAttrList *attr_of_label=pango_attr_list_new();
/*здесь наверное нужно как-то запихнуть color в attr_of_label, но функция pango_attr_list_insert () слишком запутанная, она требует во втором аргументе еще какую-то структуру*/
gtk_label_set_attributes (GTK_LABEL(label),attr_of_label)// -- и установить атрибуты
```

Хотелось бы еще толщину и другие атрибуты настраивать

P.s Я программист-любитель, поэтому сам буду разбираться часа 3 с такой мелочью, но есть возможность пополнить стековерфлоу полезным вопросом и продолжить дальше разработку

Comment: pango это библиотека отображения шрифтов , нужно настроить шрифты или всетаки виджет GTL_LABEL ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используя [API pango](https://developer.gnome.org/pango/stable/pango-Text-Attributes.html) создаете нужные атрибуты и формируете список атрибутов

```
PangoAttrList *attr_of_label=pango_attr_list_new();

PangoAttribute * atr_weight = pango_attr_weight_new (PANGO_WEIGHT_NORMAL); 
PangoAttribute * atr_background = pango_attr_background_new (0xFF, 0x00, 0x00);
... 
pango_attr_list_insert(attr_of_label, atr_weight); 
pango_attr_list_insert(attr_of_label, atr_background);
...
gtk_label_set_attributes(GTK_LABEL(label),attr_of_label)// -- и установить атрибуты
```